# Does AKS api service authorized ip ranges include azure devops automatically?

Tags: azure-container-service

Azure advisor linked this resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/api-server-authorized-ip-ranges on our AKS. Does this automatically include hosted Azure devops build agents?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to enable Azure Devops to talk to your locked down API Server is to augment the range of IPs with the IP from your specific Azure DevOps region's IP.

From this issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49578

it is noted that

```
Only way is to add the ips used by the azure pipelines of that region to the authorized ips list.

Also we need to update the ips when it changes for that region.

Please provide a feedback here for improvement.

Community can vote on this feedback and product teams will look into this items to build their backlog
```

I suggest you to follow up with this thread to see how MSFT will be providing a better solution: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/54753

Note that it was also reported on the VSCode page:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/947371/allow-devops-environments-communication-with-prote.html